# IIS7 broken by apache install

Tags: apache, iis

We have a VPS running 5 sites, which were all working correctly up until last night.

I installed Xampp & Apache in an effort to run apache & IIS alongside each other.

All seemed to be going well, i had both servers running, however this morning all the sites seem to have gone down, IIS couldnt start & getting "unable to connect" messages in the browser.

After reading around I'm pretty certain this is Apache taking over port 80.

Since then i've uninstalled apache & xampp to try get the sites back up, however still not working.

The sites load correctly using localhost but not using 127.0.0.1.

I've tried telnet to 127.0.0.1 but can't get a connection

I've checked the IIS config for each site & all bindings are set to port 80

i've also done netstat -ano which shows only one thing listening on port 80 which is PID 4 - "system"

Is there anything else i can do to try debug / fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Just a quick update, I've double checked all the application pools in IIS are running & there are no errors in the event viewer.

Comment: tried to ask in people in [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/) ? it's have been 7 days since you asked..